# Add round feedback arrow to horizontal graph in Graphviz / DiagrammR

Tags: r, graphviz, pygraphviz

I like to add a feedback arrow to a **Graphviz** graph, where the ordinary "flow" remains horizontal, but the feedback should be round, like the manually added blue arrow below.

Here is what I tried so far. I use the **DiagrammR** package for the **R** language but a suggestion for plain or **python** Graphviz or would of course also be helpful.

```r
library("DiagrammeR")
grViz("digraph feedback {
         graph [rankdir = 'LR']
           node [shape = box]
             Population
           node [shape = circle]
             Source Sink
           node [shape = none]
             Source -> Growth -> Population -> Death -> Sink
             
             Population -> Growth [constraint = false]
             Death -> Population [constraint = false]
}")
```

[image: feedback arrow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the headport and tailport options and indicate "north" for both of these (for Population and Growth).

The headport is the cardinal direction for where the arrowhead meets the node.

The tailport is the cardinal direction for where the tail is emitted from the node.

```
library("DiagrammeR")
grViz("digraph feedback {
         graph [rankdir = 'LR']
           node [shape = box]
             Population
           node [shape = circle]
             Source Sink
           node [shape = none]
             Source -> Growth -> Population -> Death -> Sink
             Population -> Growth [tailport = 'n', headport = 'n', constraint = false]
}")
```

**Output**

[image: diagrammeR example with curved arrow]

Comment: Great! Thanks @Ben! Now the only remaining cosmetic question is how to change circle nodes to somewhat similar to a cloud symbol.

Comment: Glad to hear. Cloud symbol may be tough! I didn't see that shape available with grViz. I did see [another example](https://www.noahlandesberg.com/blog/post/thinking-in-systems-with-diagrammer/) that used the triple octagon to represent a cloud...not quite the same. Good luck!